Find appropriate rotation matrix with non-square matrices
In linear algebra, consider::
$$\pmb{G}: L \times K$$ matrix
$$\pmb{F}: T \times K$$ matrix
$$\pmb{H}: T \times L$$ matrix.
The apex $\intercal$ denotes the transpose. It holds that $T > L > K$
I want to find a matrix $\pmb{R}$, $K \times K$, such that:
$$\pmb{G} \pmb{R} \pmb{F}^{\intercal} = \pmb{H}^{\intercal}$$
My guess would be $\pmb{R} = \pmb{G}^{-1} \pmb{H} \pmb{F'}^{-1}$
where in this case the apex -1 denotes the pseudo-inverse of a matrix as we have non-squared matrices except for $\pmb{R}$. However, when I bring this solution to test with data, I do not get that $\pmb{G} \pmb{R} \pmb{F}^{\intercal} = \pmb{H}^{\intercal}$. Something is wrong with the data dimensions: $\pmb{G}^{-1} \pmb{G}$ gives me a $K \times K$ matrix but what I would need is an $L \times L$ matrix to be compatible with $\pmb{G}\pmb{G}^{-1} \pmb{R} \pmb{F}^{\intercal}\pmb{F}^{\intercal-1} = \pmb{H}^{\intercal}$. Is this happening because $L > K$? Does a solution $\pmb{R}$ even exist in this framework?

$GRF^T$ cannot be equal $H$ because it has the wrong (transposed) dimensions. However, it is dimensionally compatible with $H^{\bf+}$ or $H^T;$

true. that was a typo from my side, thank you for pointing that out

With the typo fixed that makes the solution $:R=G^{-1},H^T,(F^T)^{-1}\quad$

The solution in my previous comment is the least-squares solution, but isn't necessarily orthogonal. You can calculate the nearest orthogonal matrix to the LS solution via Polar decomposition $$ R_p=R,\big(R^TR\big)^{-1/2} $$ but I'm not sure if the matrix $R_p$ is the global solution of the original problem.

Assume $G,F$ have full column rank
$$
G^{-1}=(G^TG)^{-1} G^T
$$
$$
(F^T)^{-1}=F(F^{T}F)^{-1}
$$
We have
$$
G^{-1}G R F^T (F^T)^{-1}=R=G^{-1} H (F^T)^{-1} 
$$
Btw i don't see how
$
GG^{-1} R F^T(F^T)^{-1}=H
$. Assuming $G^{-1}$ is the Penrose pseudo-inverse of a full rank matrix this would imply that $R=H$

corrected the typo, you were right.
